# What are these banners better called or know as?

Tags: football, terminology, fans

This is a picture of Polish football fans holding banners.

[image]

What is the name of these kind of banners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ["scarf"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarf#Sport) (English); Or "cachecol" (Portuguese, as myself and the guys on wikipedia's picture :-), from the French "cache-col" (to cover the neck), also "écharpe" (French)

Usually you do wear them around the neck, or may waive it as a flag.

Comment: Yay..Thanks Mate!! This is what I wanted..Cheers!!

Comment: Bufanda (in spanish) ;)